# python avoiding %s in sql query

Tags: python, sql

I am trying to query a mysql db from python but having troubles generating the query ebcasue of the wildcard % and python's %s. As a solution I find using ?, but when I run the following,

```
query = '''select * from db where name like'Al%' and date = '%s' ''', myDateString
```

I get an error

```
cursor.execute(s %'2015_05_21')
```

ValueError: unsupported format character ''' (0x27) at index 36 (the position of %)

How can i combine python 2.7 string bulding and sql wildcards? (The actual query is a lot longer and involves more variables)

Comment: Possibly unrelated, but you'll typically need to use `LIKE` (not =) to use a wildcard like 'Al%'

Comment: thanks Stuart. Type - edited now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you need to escape the percent sign near the `Al`:

```
'''select * from db where name like 'Al%%' and date = '%s''''
```

Also, follow the best practices and pass the query parameters in the second argument to `execute()`. This way your query parameters would be escaped and you would avoid sql injections:

```
query = """select * from db where name like 'Al%%' and date = %s"""
cursor.execute(query, ('2015_05_21', ))
```

Comment: thanks, that works for the example. in my query, I need to combine wildcard and string building like
select * from table where name like 'A%% %s' and date = %s.
seems like sql does not like having %s within quotation marks. How can i work around that?

Comment: @chrise in that case you can use `format()` with `MySQLdb.escape_string`, e.g. `query = """select * from db where name like 'Al%% {0}' and date = %s""".format(MySQLdb.escape_string(param))`.

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. Don't use string formatting (`'%s' % some_var`) in SQL queries. Instead, pass the string as a sequence (like a list or a tuple) to the execute method.
2. You can escape your `%` so Python will not expect a format specifier:

   ```
   q = 'SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE zoo LIKE 'abc%%' and id = %s'
   cursor.execute(q, (some_var,))
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `format` syntax for Python string building, and `%s` for `SQL` interpolation. That way they don't conflict with each other.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the `?` correctly.

Here's an example:

`command = '''SELECT M.name, M.year
             FROM Movie M, Person P, Director D
             WHERE M.id = D.movie_id
               AND P.id = D.director_id
               AND P.name = ?
               AND M.year BETWEEN ? AND ?;'''`

*Execute the command, replacing the placeholders with the values of 
 the variables in the list [dirName, start, end]. *

`cursor.execute(command, [dirName, start, end])`

So, you want to try:

`cursor.execute(query,'2015_05_21')`

Comment: Did you actually try this code? It won't work. `.execute` expects a sequence, and you are passing it a string.